# Dismissing an alert dialog with custom Anko layout DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have created the following alert dialog with a simple view comprising of a `TextView`, `EditText` and `Button`:

```
alert {
            customView {
                verticalLayout {
                    textView {
                        text = getString(R.string.enter_quantity)
                        textSize = 18f
                        textColor = Color.BLACK
                    }.lparams {
                        topMargin = dip(17)
                        horizontalMargin = dip(17)
                        bottomMargin = dip(10)
                    }

                    val quantity = editText {
                        inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@ProductsList, R.drawable.textbox_bg)
                    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent) {
                        bottomMargin = dip(10)
                        horizontalMargin = dip(17)
                    }

                    button(getString(R.string.confirm)) {
                        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@ProductsList, R.color.colorPrimary)
                        textColor = Color.WHITE
                    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent) {
                        topMargin = dip(10)
                    }.setOnClickListener {
                        if (quantity.text.isNullOrBlank())
                            snackbar(parentLayout!!, getString(R.string.enter_valid_quantity))
                        else
                            addToCart(product, quantity.text.toString().toInt())
                    }
                }
            }
        }.show()
```

I want to dismiss it whenever the button is clicked and the `if-else` clause has been executed. I tried using `this@alert` but it doesn't provide the dialog methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is problematic because your `button` function call which registers the listener executes when the dialog doesn't even exist yet.

Here's one way to do it, using a local [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) variable to make the `dialog` available inside the listener:

```
lateinit var dialog: DialogInterface
dialog = alert {
    customView {
        button("Click") {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}.show()
```

You could also assign the result of the builder to a class property, etc. Note that `lateinit` for local variables is available [since Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables).

Comment: Using `DialogInterface` as the variable type brings up a `conflicting declarations` error message on the editor; and so does `AlertBuilder<DialogInterface>`

Comment: What's the full error message? Perhaps you already have a variable named `dialog` in scope?

Comment: You're right, I had a conflicting variable named `dialog`. Renaming it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply, `it.dismiss()` inside yes or no button callback, like this here `it` is `DialogInterface`:

```
alert(getString(R.string.logout_message),getString(R.string.logout_title)){
        yesButton {
            // some code here
            it.dismiss()
        }
        noButton {
            it.dismiss()
        }
    }.show()
```